# Java thin-like web server

Tags: java, webserver

Is there any non-blocking servers for Java (like `thin` for RoR and `node.js` for JS)?
It would be nice if this server could be embeddable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/) is a embeddable server (and servlet container) based exclusively on non-blocking I/O (`java.nio` package). [Netty](http://netty.io/) is another choice.

Answer (score 1):

I have some doubts it's what you're after but [Play](http://www.playframework.com/) is a non-blocking async I/O web framework with integrated server (not "just" a web server).